# Linking Verb Following a Past Participle?

Tags: tenses

I am writing an essay and it requires ALL present tense phrases.

One of my phrases:

> is described

Would that be considered a present tense phrase? Or would it count as past tense?

Is it a linking verb following a past participle?

Comment: Present tense is *am, is, are*. Past tense is *was, were*.

Comment: Is/am/are described is the passive voice of describe(s), but of course present tense.

Answer (score 1):

Even though we call it "the past participle", on its own it has nothing to do with the past.  Participles, gerunds and infinitives are all non-finite forms.  They carry no tense at all.  They easily combine with any tense.

> was described -- past
>   is described -- present
>   will be described -- future

The "is described" example employs the present tense and the passive voice.  Whatever is described, something describes or has described it.

Another construction that uses participles expresses what we call the perfect aspect:

> had described -- past
>   has described -- present
>   will have described -- future

Comment: Thanks so much! I have a lot more confidence in my essay now! I just realized most of the mistakes I thought I made are actually correct, thank you.